# Move data from 1 hard drive to the other

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, partition, external-disk

I have a bootable partition on an external drive with some old data that I want to move to a new external hard drive. The partition on the old drive is 500GB however theres only 320GB of data. So i want to keep the partition bootable and resize it so that I don't have 180GB wasted on my new hard drive. How can I do this with disk utility?

Comment: Apple/Mac has something called Migration Assistant already installed in your Utility folder.

Answer (score 1):

I think most disk imaging utilities will do what you are looking to achieve. Try Partition Magic or Macrium Reflect. In fact I know for sure that Partition Magic will automatically estimate the needed and resize the space as needed based on the original hard disk (and its partition) and the destination disk.

Comment: Are these software suggestions OS X software?

Comment: Hi Dean, no. As far as I know they are PC tools. For Mac use the built-in Migration Assistant as suggested by Buscar above.